# Incorrect launch ETS 2 on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: games, steam

I'm trying to launch ETS 2, but for some reason, the game doesn't launch as I expected.

[image: incorrect launch ets2 image]

I tried to launch the game with the settings -fullscreen, and -windows_pos, as well as launch the game using different versions of Proton for compatibility. The game does not launch when using other versions of Proton.

How to fix it?

Comment: You have not clearly explained your issue. "Not as I expected" means nothing because no one knows what you expected, or what actually happened. Your post boils down to "I have a problem with this game."

Answer (score 0):

The window can be moved with alt+super key, You might be required to get out of the window with super at first, so your mouse is not captured by ETS.

Then for fullscreen go to **settings>refresh rate** and try changing it to another value (you can then change it back to your desired), this should make the window turn into fullscreen.

[Tested on Ubuntu 23.10, using Demo version and Proton Experimental]